# How to get readable stacktrace for Dart code exception with Firebase Crashlytics in Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I've followed integration guide and integrated Firebase Crashlytics into my Flutter app.
When testing with `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();` I expect to see a readable Dart stacktrace of the exception to know the line number at least. Instead i can see the following in Firebase:

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlyticsTestCrash
This is a test crash caused by calling .crash() in Dart.
io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.lambda$crash$1 (FlutterFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.java:77)
io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.-$$Lambda$FlutterFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin$S7-ndFU6gs1AKgZZJXppPdTcLo8.run
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7560)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Here are the integration changes:

"pubspec.yaml":

```
  firebase_analytics: ^9.0.2
  firebase_core: "^1.10.0"
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.4.0
```

"android.build.gradle":

```
buildscript {
...
  dependencies {
  ...
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
  classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
  ...
```

"android/app/build.gradle":

```
...
// firebase
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
...
   release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.googleplaySigningConfig

            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                strippedNativeLibsDir "build/app/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/release/out/lib"
                unstrippedNativeLibsDir "build/app/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib"
            }

            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
            }
        } 
...
```

Note i had to specify `strippedNativeLibsDir` and `unstrippedNativeLibsDir` as otherwise it failed with "Crashlytics could not determine unstripped native library directories for project ':app', variant Release. These are required".

"main.dart"

```
Future<void> main() async {
  runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    // Pass all uncaught errors from the framework to Crashlytics.
    FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
 ...
      FirebaseAnalytics.instance.setUserId(id: uuid);
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setUserIdentifier(uuid);

      await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
      await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
      await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.sendUnsentReports();
...
runApp(MyApp());
  }, (error, stack) => FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack));
}
```

The app is build with `flutter build appbundle`.
In build log i can see:

```
[        ] Unable to extract native debug metadata from /Users/developer/Documents/dev/src/myapp/build/app/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libapp.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
```

and libapp.so is stripped in both "merged_native_libs" and "stripped_native_libs". **I was unable to find libapp.so which is not stripped.**

BTW i leave only arm64 files:

```
   ...
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a" // to reduce all the other ARCHs except this
        }
    }
    ...
```

Is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: Have you found any solutions so far? I am struggling with the same problem for days now. I don use `abiFilters` but otherwise my issue is exactly the same.

Comment: @PeterKoltai nope, haven't found a solution